# Binding ActiveX events within Javascript

Tags: javascript, activex

I'm trying to simplify an IE ActiveX project into a single.js file and I'm having some trouble with ActiveX events

The project has them defined as but I would like to move the entire script tag into the js file and allow people to add an EventListener to the event if they need to be notified of it.

```
<script for="Component" event="TargetEvent(args)" language="javascript">Component_TargetEvent(args)</script>
```

Trying to bind the the event itself has not worked. I have tried the following items but I still get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." and "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" respectively.

```
function Component.TargetEvent(args){}

function Component::TargetEvent(args){}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but what about `Component.TargetEvent = function(args){};`?

Comment: That fixed it, you da man!

Comment: Okay, well I've made an answer. You're free to accept it if that's all that was needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Component.TargetEvent = function(args) {};
```

Comment: The hero we all want.